# Uninstall Win 8 PK from Win 7-running computer

Tags: windows, license

I recently wanted to switch the windows 8 from a computer to another, but completely forgot to uninstall the product key and did a clean install of  windows 7 over it (shift-F10-diskpart type of clean install). Then, when I tried to activate the previosuly removed Windoes 8 on the other computer, it accepted the key during the installation process, but did not want to activate as soon as winddows finished installing and loaded the desktop.

I tried reintroducing the key in the windows activation menu in settings, but it wouldn't take it.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

There's no "product key uninstallation" or "windows deactivation" for Windows.

OEM keys can't be activated on different hardware.

What you could try is do phone activation and tell the operator that a lightning forced you to change most hardware. (Last time I tried this was in 2004, right now I don't know if you can speak with an operator after the automated voice)